# How to get exact date from 30 days from specific date?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have mysql date like this `2013-10-16 17:44:13` and I need to get +30 days from there. I can't use eg. 10th ( month ) and change it to 11th ( month ) as this may be 31 day or 29 depending on the month

I can only think of converting `2013-10-16 17:44:13` to timestamp than + 30*24*60*30, and than this new timestamp back to mysql format

Is there a better way?

Comment: 1. There are 60 seconds in a minute, not 30. [`30*24*60*60`] 2. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net) for this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date . ' +30 days'));
```

or do it directly in MySQL using [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 30 DAY) as `date` FROM `table`
```

If you run a newer version of MySQL, you don't need to use `DATE_ADD`:

```
SELECT (`date` + INTERVAL 30 DAY) as `date` FROM `table`
```

Please note that while `strtotime` is smart enough, MySQL **requires** you to use `DAY`. Not `DAYS`.

***Edit**: I am unable to find any proof of `DATE_ADD` being needed in older versions, but I swear that I've heard it somewhere. Take it with a grain of salt and use whatever method you prefer.*

Answer (score 2):

since you mentioned mysql you an do it with mysql functions

```
select NOW() + interval 30 day as NEW_DATE
```

NOW, could be replaced with a date in your db

```
select date_field + interval 30 day as NEW_DATE from YOUR_DB
```